# Importing a dump.sql into Postgres Database using command prompt

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I'm using my Windows PC, and I'm trying to import a "dump.sql" into the database "TEST" created with Postgres, using command prompt. I do it in two steps:

*Step 1:*

```
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin
```

*Step 2:*

```
psql -U username -d TEST < C:\Users\Username\Desktop\University\Politechnic\III year\INFORMATIC TECHNOLOGIES FOR THE WEB\PDF SL\SL\Materials\TIW_IOL_ServletJSP\db\dump.sql`
```

Long path, I know. But the result is: "Impossible to find specified file".

What can I do?

Comment: Sorry I forget what Windows behavior is like -- do you need double-quotes `"` for folder names that have spaces?

Comment: I don't think so, because the path specified in the first step contains a directory named with a space in between the two words, and yet even tho I didn't add any double quotes " the path have been accepted without problems.

Comment: Not sure how security is where you are at, but can you attempt to write to a file with a simpler destination? Such that you take out any possibility of spaces and/or length being the issue? Then you will at least be able to remove those variables or narrow down to them depending on the outcome.

Comment: @dmoore1181 you are right, with shorter path finally works. I still wonder why... a path should be  a precise "way to follow" as it is.

Comment: The max path length in windows is 260 characters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file, so I wouldn't think that would be the answer in your case. I would venture that the spaces may have had more to do with it. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how security is where you are at, but can you attempt to write to a file with a simpler destination? Such that you take out any possibility of spaces and/or length being the issue? Then you will at least be able to remove those variables or narrow down to them depending on the outcome. Note that the max path length is 260 characters

(From comment on question)

Comment: Your answer have been useful to fix my problem, i moved the directory to a shorter Path (basically few levels below C:) and now it works. Thank you!